# Correct place to programmatically launch view controller: willFinishLaunching vs didFinishLaunching?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This probably has very little impact on performance, but I noticed that a lot of posts and tutorials simply instantiate and set the root view controller in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

However, there is actually a method that is not included in the default AppDelegate template file that gets fired off first:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Is there any difference between instantiating your view controller's in either of these? Just preference or laziness?

Comment: `willFinishLaunching` is called before state restoration occurs and `didFinishLaunching` afterwards.  If you aren't using state restoration then there it doesn't matter which one you use AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between these involves state restoration (using [`application:shouldSaveApplicationState`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623089-application?language=objc) and [`application:shouldRestoreApplicationState`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622987-application?language=objc). The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623032-application) for `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` notes: "If your app relies on the state restoration machinery to restore its view controllers, always show your app’s window from this method." If you're not doing anything with state restoration, it probably doesn't make any real difference which one you use.